# Processing a LOG file on an automounted CIFS host, which is frequently turned OFF

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, logging, mount, cifs

So I am new to Ubuntu and I have some **log files on a windows machine, which I should process frequently**. On my ubuntu server there is a service which watches for file changes and processes the logs.

The **windows machines's C drive** is mounted on the Ubuntu server, and today I succesfully configured the **/etc/fstab** file, so the drive is  **automatically mounted** on reboot.

**The problem is that the windows machine is turned off at the end of every shift.**

Theres a **Node.js** program on my server, which constantly **tries to access the file**, and when it's available, **watches the log file and processes the constantly inserted new lines**. If the machine is turned off, **it tries to reach the file over again**.

The question is:

**What happens if the ubuntu server reboots**(because of any known or unknown cause)**, and cant find the windows machine to mount its C drive?** While I was configuring the ftsab and messed up the config, the whole system became read-only so I guess not findig the machine to connect could be a problem. What could be the solution?

*Is my approach to the problem is correct? If not, what could be a better solution? I would rather just read the data form the windows machine, I wouldnt like to install any program on it which sends data, or anything like that.*

Answer (score 0):

Current, working solution:

Remove the mounting from **fstab** and manage it from the Node.js app, with executing shell commands, with **execSync**:

```js
async function mountDrive() {
  if (process.platform === "win32") {
    //on windows the drive shouldnt be explicitly mounted
    let folderExists = false;
    while (!folderExists) {
      logger.info(
        "Trying to reach destination folder: " + config.sourceFolderPath
      );
      if (fs.existsSync(config.sourceFolderPath)) {
        //if folder found exit the loop
        folderExists = true;
        logger.info("Target folder found!");
      } else {
        //if folder not found try again in config.timeout seconds
        logger.warn(
          "Target folder not found, trying again in " +
            config.timeout +
            " seconds..."
        );
        await sleep(config.timeout * 1000);
        continue;
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  if (process.platform === "linux") {
    let driveMounted = false;
    while (!driveMounted) {
      logger.info(
        "Check if target folder is mounted: " + config.sourceFolderPath
      );
      //the mounted path
      let mountedPath = "";
      //get the mounted path if any
      try {
        let mountGrepResponse = execSync(
          `mount | grep ${config.sourceFolderPath}`
        ).toString("utf-8");

        mountedPath = mountGrepResponse.split("type")[0].split("on")[1].trim();

        logger.info(`Target folder is mounted at: ${mountedPath}`);
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Drive isn't mounted, trying to mount it...");
      }

      //if drive is not mounted try to mount it
      if (mountedPath.length === 0) {
        try {
          execSync(
            `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=guest,password= ${config.sourceFolderPath} ${config.mountFolderPath}`
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(
            "Host unavailable, trying again in" + config.timeout + " seconds..."
          );
          await sleep(config.timeout * 1000);
          continue;
        }
      }
      
      driveMounted=true;
    }

    return;
  }
```